# How to define a function use loop and return multi-values

Tags: python

like this code

```
list1 = [1,3,2,4,2]
list2 = [1,5,6,3,2]
def dif(list1,list2):
    # listdif = []
    for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if (first != second):
            print(index,first,second)
            #listdif.append(index,first,second)
        #return listdif()


print(dif(list1,list2))
```

it's print

```
PS C:\Users\ssc\Desktop\Dou> & C:/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/ssc/Desktop/Dou/test.py
1 3 5
2 2 6
3 4 3
None
```

But I want this function can ***renturn*** this result to a list or other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
list1 = [1,3,2,4,2]
list2 = [1,5,6,3,2]

def dif(list1,list2):
    listdif = []
    for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if (first != second):
            listdif.append((index,first,second))
    return listdif

print(dif(list1,list2))
```

Result:

```
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 2, 6), (3, 4, 3)]
```